# Use curl to batch process GCM tokens

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a `.csv` file with a bunch of android tokens. For all of these tokens I want to check if they're still valid. In the end I want a `.csv` file with an extra column that's called "valid" which can be either 0 or 1. (0 if it's not, 1 if it is).

I want to check each of the tokens by the following command:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=[my API key]" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"[my token]\"]}"
```

If the response is

```
{  
   "multicast_id":[  
      id
   ],
   "success":0,
   "failure":1,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "error":"InvalidRegistration"
      }
   ]
}
```

the token is invalid and I want the column "valid" to be set to 0.

How can I set up a script that automatically checks each token in the `.csv` separately and updates the column 'valid' with the right value?

Comment: ok, post your .csv file with a bunch of android tokens, at least a few lines

Comment: Why would you use `curl` and shell for this, instead of a language that can make multiple HTTP requests without spawning a new process for each?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use GNU `awk` (that'll [simplify CSV parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/404556)), and your tokens are stored in the *second column* (notice `$2` in `awk` line) of the `tokens.csv`:

```
#!/bin/bash

is_token_invalid() {
    args=(
        -s
        -H 'Authorization: key=[my API key]'
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
        -d '{"registration_ids": ["'"$1"'"]}'
        'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
    )
    curl "${args[@]}" | grep -q InvalidRegistration
}

awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '{print $2}' tokens.csv | 
    while read token; do
        is_token_invalid "$token" && echo 1 || echo 0
    done | paste -d, tokens.csv -
```

Comment: I like this; much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the format of your CSV file, it's difficult to give a solution. Using a mock up CSV file with 4 columns, you could do something very crudely like this:

```
$ cat test.csv
blah,blah,token1,blah
blah,blah,token2,blah
blah,blah,token3,blah
$ ./test.sh < test.csv
blah,blah,token1,blah,1
blah,blah,token2,blah,1
blah,blah,token3,blah,1
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

invalid_response () {
  cat << 'EOF'
{
   "multicast_id":[
      id
   ],
   "success":0,
   "failure":1,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[
      {
         "error":"InvalidRegistration"
      }
   ]
}
EOF
}

is_invalid_token () {
  declare token="${1:-}"
  [[ "$(curl -sSL \
    --header "Authorization: key=[my API key]" \
    --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
    https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
    -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"$token\"]}")" == "$(invalid_response)" ]]
}

main () {
  declare token="" valid=""
  while IFS="," read -r col1 col2 token col4 valid ; do
    valid=1
    if is_invalid_token "$token" ; then
      valid=0
    fi
    printf "$col1,$col2,$token,$col4,$valid\n"
  done
}

main "$@"
```

This isn't a great solution as it re-constructs every CSV line in its entirety, and it is comparing the JSON response against your literal string example.

It would better to know precisely what part of the response should be taken to mean valid or invalid, and use a tool like `jq` to parse the response for the specific data you want to test against.